# Facebook Page photo privacy

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-photos

Is there any way to stop someone from liking my Facebook Business Page's photos if they haven't already liked the page? Is there any way to protect the Facebook Page photos?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to secure pages like this. Pages by design are public for purposes like these.